# Returning to main menu after calling a different script

Tags: menu, case

I am having a menu based script which calls for an additional shell script.
The challenge is that, after the additional shell script is finished, instead of returning to the main menu, it exits completely.

The code is something like this:

```
options=("Deploy code" "Backup a directory or file" "Transfer file SCP" "Start tool b" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"; do
   case $REPLY in
      1) command1; break;;
      2) sh ./backup-script.sh; break;;
      3) test1; break;;
      4) bla2; break;;
      5) break 2 ;;
      *) echo "Invalid option selected" >&2
   esac
done
```

backup-script.sh is having the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define params
read -p "Provide full path of file(s) or folder(s) you want to create a backup of: " param_backup
backed_up_path=$(echo "${param_backup}_bkp_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")");

# execute backup with params
echo 
echo "Attempting to create backup of specified file(s) or folder(s)..."
if cp -prvf ${param_backup} ${backed_up_path} 
    then
        echo
        printf "\033[1;32mSUCCESS: Backup created!\033[0m\n"
    else
        echo 
        printf "\033[1;31mERROR: There was an error and the backup could not be performed.\033[0m\n"
        printf "\033[1;31m       Please try again and make sure that the source path is valid or exists!\033[0m\n"
fi
echo
```

Tried sourcing the script and then using return function, but it didn't helped (or I have done something wrong).

Any idea on how to return to the main menu after the backup-script.sh is finishing running?

Thank you!

Comment: If you have written `backup-script.sh` as a `bash` script (see its first line), _do not_ call it with `sh`. In many cases `sh` is not the same as `bash`. Either use `bash` to call it or (better) make the script executable with `chmod a+x backup-script.sh` and then just invoke it as `./backup-script.sh`.

Comment: Double-quote your variables whenever you use them. Otherwise you _will_ encounter problems with filenames such as those containing a space. For a backup script it is particularly important to get this right

Comment: Likely it *does* return to the main menu - however you then immediately `break` out of the `select` loop. I think perhaps you are misunderstanding the role of `break` here (i.e. thinking it is breaking out of the `case` construct - bash case...esac does not "drop through" in the same way as in some languages).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work as expected by using:

```
backup () { 
   ./backup_script.sh
   read -rsn1 -p "Press any key to go back to main menu"
   clear
}

options=("Deploy code" "Backup a directory or file" "Transfer file SCP" "Start tool b" "Quit")
select opt in "${options[@]}"; do
   case $REPLY in
      1) command1; ;;
      2) backup; ;;
      3) test1; ;;
      4) bla2; ;;
      5) break 2 ;;
      *) echo "Invalid option selected" >&2
   esac
done
```